# I am trying to check if an array is increasing in both rows and columns, how do i do this? I know you need to compare the previous to the current

Tags: java

I am trying to check if an array is increasing in both rows and columns

```
  public static boolean increasingArray(int[][] a) {

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         for(int row = 0; row< a.length row > previous)
         for(int col= 0; col< a.length col > previous)
          return true;
        }
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: 1) define what's the problem?  2) what's the question?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the question is to check to see if an array is increasing in every row and every column.  this is my code so far but it is failing and I am not sure why it is.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Number one: The above is a combination of Java and Javascript.  Number two: you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please take the StackOverflow [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out how to ask questions here.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve about the right way to ask questions when things aren't working.  Basically, simply throwing code at us and saying "this is failing" is not the way to do it.

Comment: I didn't try but I'm pretty confident this is not going to compile... `row< a.length row > previous`

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but your coding examples show that you don't have a grasp of the fundamentals yet.  You'll need a tutor or someone to walk you through how to write code.  StackOverflow can't help you with that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "if" statement and just enter the statement you want.
If I understand correctly you want something like this :

```
    1 2 
    3 4
```

So if you want to compare 1 and 2 use j and j + 1 if you want to compare 
1 and 3 use i and i + 1. Make sure control the last row and column, you can pass the limit of array.

```
    public static boolean increasingArray(int[][] array) {
    boolean result = true;
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j != n - 1 && array[i][j] >= array[i][j + 1])
                result = false;
            else if (i != n - 1 && array[i][j] >= array[i + 1][j])
                result = false;
            else
                result = true;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```